# JSX how to return an image correctly? Üebersicht widget

Tags: image, widget, runtime-error, jsx

I would like to return an image as a widget.

I put my  **photo.png** in a folder *images* next to **myFile.jsx**.

I have always the same error :

**Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module './images/photo.png' form /Users/macbookpro/Library/Application Support/Übersicht/widgets/my file/myFile.jsx required by /Users/macbookpro/Library/Application Support/Übersicht/widgets/my file/myFile.jsx**

I have also tried to: move the photo to my Desktop, use `require`, use `import .. from ..`.

Here there is the code:

```
import { css } from "uebersicht";
// import photo from "./images/photo.jpg";
// import photo from "./Users/macbookpro/Desktop/photo.png";

export const render = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src="./images/photo.png" />
      {/* <img src="./Users/macbookpro/Desktop/photo.png" /> */}
      {/* <img src={require("./images/photo.png")} /> */}
      {/* <img src={require("./Users/macbookpro/Desktop/photo.png")} /> */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since myFile.jsx is actually act as a component for uebersicht you have to include your widget folder name in you src.

For example if your photo.png is in example.widget/images folder, your  should be:

> <img src="example.widget/images/photo.png/>